# Throwing Exception in Foreach/Map Block

Tags: scala

I am very curious as to why the exception is thrown in the following `foreach` block.  I would expect that no values make it past the filter and thus the `foreach` block is never reached.  The same behavior occurs with `map`.

```
scala> (1 to 10) filter { _ > 12 } foreach { throw new Exception }
java.lang.Exception
  ... 33 elided
```

I would expect the exception to not to be thrown and behave more like the following where `println` is never executed.

```
scala> (1 to 10) filter { _ > 12 } foreach { println _ }
```

Maybe this has to do with how exceptions are handled?  Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{ throw new Exception }
```

is just a block which throws an exception - as a result it has type `Nothing`. Since `Nothing` is a subtype of all types, it is compatible with `Function[Int, T]` which is required as the argument to the `foreach` block.

You can see this more clearly if you create the function beforehand:

```
//throws exception
val f: Function[Int, Unit] = { throw new Exception }
```

If you want to create a `Function[Int, Nothing]` you need to add the parameter to the block:

```
(1 to 10) filter { _ > 12 } foreach { _ => throw new Exception }
```

Comment: In other words, the expression `throw new Exception` is a by-value argument to the function foreach, so it is evaluated prior to the execution of the larger expression. `_ => throw new Exception` is also evaluated first, but it evaluates to a function object (which never gets called when the larger expression executes).

Comment: @SteveWaldman I think that is a better answer. Lee's at a glance just seems to point out why this compiles